# How can I adjust the R code to get data for 2019 and 2020

Tags: r

I have the R code below that gets me financial data for a company for 2018 from the following table:
[image: Table]

```
  # Extract all data tables
```

data1_2 <- webpage2 %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="tabElemNoBor overfH fvtDiv"]')

# Getting data from annual income statement
  error_list_2 <- c()
  for (j in 1:length(data1_2)){

```
tryCatch({
  data2_2 <- data1_2[[j]] %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
  if (grepl("Annual Income Statement", data2_2[1,1])){

    data2_2 <- data2_2[4:nrow(data2_2),]

    units <- data2_2[1,4]
    units <- substr(units, regexpr("Actuals in ", units) + 11, nchar(units))

    year <- data2_2[2,4]
    fiscal <- data2_2[2,1]

    sales_pos <- grep("Sales", data2_2[,1])
    ebitda_pos <- grep("EBITDA", data2_2[,1])
    ebit_pos <- grep("Operating profit", data2_2[,1])
    ebt_pos <- grep("Pre-Tax Profit", data2_2[,1])
    net_income_pos <- grep("Net income", data2_2[,1])
    pe_ratio_pos <- grep("P/E ratio", data2_2[,1])
    eps_pos <- grep("EPS", data2_2[,1])

    sales <- as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", data2_2[sales_pos,4]))
    ebitda <- as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", data2_2[ebitda_pos,4]))
    ebit <- as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", data2_2[ebit_pos,4]))
    ebt <- as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", data2_2[ebt_pos,4]))
    net_income <- as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", data2_2[net_income_pos,4]))
    pe_ratio <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", data2_2[pe_ratio_pos,4]))
    eps <- (gsub(",", ".", data2_2[eps_pos,4]))
    eps <- as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", eps))

  }
}, error = function(e) {e; error_list_2 <<- c(error_list_2, j)})
```

}

Can you please tell me how I can modify the code so I can get data for 2019 and 2020 years ?

Can I please have a full answer as I know almost nothing about R and please no newbie bashing :-)

Comment: i think you just need to change the '4' to a '5' for year 2019 and to a '6' for year 2020 in the last rows. for example:  sales <- as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", data2_2[sales_pos,5]))

Comment: Do you need an r or python solution? Use the python tag if you need answers dealing with python.

Comment: Jagge, that works, many thanks